# Presentation: vertical space among items in lists

Tags: feature-request, design, list

The vertical spacing between `ul` and `ol` items on StackOverflow is very tight. Would it make sense to increase the vspace between any two items in a list? This would enhance readability of posts.

Comment: It might help to show us what you're proposing it be changed to versus what it is now.

Comment: @Jon Seigel I honestly don't know, I'm not a typographer. But I can say that the spacing in a LaTeX `itemize` environment is very pleasing for the eye, so maybe stackoverflow can take its numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You

- really
- think
- this
- is
- too
- tight?

I am not sure I agree? You can of course add spaces to your list like so:

- just
- add one
- paragraph between each line

Comment: Yes, I really do. I know it's subjective, but less subjective than one may think. I also know I can add extra newlines on my own but I think this is a presentation detail, not a content detail. Not only that, but an extra newline is too much. Won't it makes sense to take ideas from LaTeX? We know LaTeX documents have appealing defaults, so why not take those we know work well?

Answer (score 0):

Or may be you just need some scripts to change line-height?

```
javascript:(function(){$("li").css({"line-height":"150%"})})()
```

<sub>**Note**: default value looks like 130%</sub>

Comment: Oh, so it's already considered and implemented in the CSS? It's just a matter of numbers?